# Trailblazer error when running operation: "NoMethodError: undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trailblazer

When I try to run a `Create` operation with the trailblazer gem, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was I wasn't including the name of the model as the root key for the hash being passed to the create operation. That is, I was calling it like this:

```
ModelClass::Create.run(some_attribute: 'attr', another_attribute: 'other_attr')
```

when I should have been passing:

```
ModelClass::Create.run(model_class: {some_attribute: 'attr', another_attribute: 'other_attr'})
```

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/apotonick/trailblazer/issues/85) where this issue is discussed. It's due to an assumption made by `validate` that the supplied hash contains a key named after the operation. The idea it's following mirrors how `params` is structured in a typical Rails app.